# BeautifulSoup get links and info inside of them

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape a website. Website has 10 preview of complaints in each page. I wrote this script to get links of 10 complaints and some info inside of each link. When I run the script I got this error message "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded".
Can someone say to me what is the problem. Thank you in advance!!

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Create list objects for each information section
C_date = []
C_title = []
C_text = []
U_name = []
U_id = []
C_count = []
R_name = []
R_date = []
R_text = []

# Get 10 links for preview of complaints
def getLinks(url):
    response = get(url)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    c_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_='media')
    # Store wanted links in a list
    allLinks = []

    for link in c_containers:
        find_tag = link.find('a')
        find_links = find_tag.get('href')
        full_link = "".join((url, find_links))
        allLinks.append(full_link)
    # Get total number of links
    print(len(allLinks))
    return allLinks

def GetData(Each_Link):
    each_complaint_page = get(Each_Link)
    html_soup = BeautifulSoup(each_complaint_page.text, 'html.parser')
    # Get date of complaint
    dt = html_soup.main.find('span')
    date = dt['title']
    C_date.append(date)
    # Get Title of complaint
    TL = html_soup.main.find('h1', {'class': 'title'})
    Title = TL.text
    C_title.append(Title)
    # Get main text of complaint
    Tx = html_soup.main.find('div', {'class': 'description'})
    Text = Tx.text
    C_text.append(Text)
    # Get user name and id
    Uname = html_soup.main.find('span', {'class': 'user'})
    User_name = Uname.span.text
    User_id = Uname.attrs['data-memberid']
    U_name.append(User_name)
    U_id.append(User_id)
    # Get view count of complaint
    Vcount = html_soup.main.find('span', {'view-count-detail'})
    View_count = Vcount.text
    C_count.append(View_count)
    # Get reply for complaint
    Rpnm = html_soup.main.find('h4', {'name'})
    Reply_name = Rpnm.next
    R_name.append(Reply_name)
    # Get reply date
    Rpdt = html_soup.main.find('span', {'date-tips'})
    Reply_date = Rpdt.attrs['title']
    R_date.append(Reply_date)
    # Get reply text
    Rptx = html_soup.main.find('p', {'comment-content-msg company-comment-msg'})
    Reply_text = Rptx.text
    R_text.append(Reply_text)


link_list = getLinks('https://www.sikayetvar.com/arcelik')

for i in link_list:
    z = GetData(i)
    print(z)
```

PS: My next step will be to put all information in a data frame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GetData()` method calls itself, with no base-case: this causes infinite recursion:

```
def GetData(data):
    for i in GetData(data):
```

You're also calling `response = get(i)` but then ignoring the result... perhaps you meant to say

```
def GetData(link):
    i = get(link)
    ...
```

Comment: I changed it into def GetData(data): for i in data. I assume that there should be two function. First one will get all related links and second one will get info inside of each link. GetLinks is designed for just one page but this url has 600 pages.

Comment: It would help if you gave your loop variables meaningful names, like `link` or `page` instead of `i`

Comment: Thanks Richards. I will do it.

Comment: So from what you're saying, `link_list` returns 600 links, and then `GetData()` processes each in turn?

Comment: For now link_list return 10 links, and then GetData process each in turn. I will create loop to get 600 links in all website.